# Showing date and time in a scatter plotly graph

Tags: python, datetime, plotly

I have this Pandas df and I would like to plot it in a Plotly scatter plot graph with this code:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x="Date", y="char_count", trendline="ols")
fig.show()
```

However it shows as axis X just the month and year, and not the day and hour and minutes that I need to do my analysis.

Anyone could help me with that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can format your plot by using the `tickformat` option. Below is a graph built based on the data you shared. It is just an example and you can edit it to see the format you want. To know of all the options available, you check [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-make-the-messy-date-ticks-organized/7477/3)
Note that the x-labels will usually start at 00:00 hrs

**Code**

```
df
>>  Date                Name            char_count
0   2022-01-06 13:49:00 Gustavo Café    29
1   2022-02-06 13:49:00 Gustavo Café    54
2   2022-03-06 14:50:00 Bruno           44
3   2022-04-06 14:50:00 Gustavo Café    55
4   2022-05-06 01:52:00 Bruno           49

fig = px.scatter(df, x="Date", y="char_count", trendline="ols")
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat = '%H : %M : %S<br>%d %B %Y')
fig.show()
```

**Output graph**

[image]